# ipad and iphone browser crashes when opening site

Tags: ios, css, iphone, html, ipad

It seems ios (ipad and iphone) crash when you change the font-size with css in an animation.
Anyone has an idea why this is and how to fix it?
Really hope someone has an answer to this. As far as I know changing font-size with css animation is completely legit.

Old question:

> I am having a crazy problem and I just have no idea what is going on.
>   I made a simple webpage that is responsive with a css animation.
>
> When someone on an ipad or iphone tries to load the page they get an
>   error and the page doesn't want to load. On android and windows it
>   works perfectly on all different browsers.
>
> I am completely clueless. Anyone got an idea?
>
> You can find the page at http://lerenlezen.brokenhip.be/

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Leren Lezen</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/default.css" />    
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="#logopedist" id="opzoek" title="Leren Lezen zoekt een logopediste. Klik Hier!">Ben jij een logopediste?</a>
                <h1>Leren Lezen</h1>
                <h2>Een acpp voor het eerste leerjaar</h2>
        </header>
        <article>
           <section>
                <h3>Een app speciaal ontwikkeld voor kinderen uit het eerste leerjaar.</h3>
                <p>Met extra aandacht voor twee- en drieklanken.</p>
                <p>Instelbaar zodat de app het specifiek leerplan exact volgt.</p>
                <p>Weldra in de Google Store!</p>
           </section>
            <form action="form_handler.php" method="post">
                <label for="email">Blijf op de hoogte:</label>
                <input name="email" id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" required />
                <input name="kind" type="hidden" value="sub" />
                <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="" />         
            </form>
        </article>
        <article id="logopedist">
            <section>
                <h3>Ben je logopediste en wil je helpen?</h3>
                <p>Leren Lezen zoekt een logopediste met perfecte uitspraak en kennis van het leerplan van het eerste leerjaar.</p>
                <p>Het zal slechts een tweetal uur van je tijd innemen, maar ondertussen zal je duizende kinderen helpen!</p>
                <p>Vul je email adres in en we zullen je zoveel mogelijk details door mailen!</p>
            </section>
            <form action="form_handler.php" method="post">
                <label for="email_logo">Ik ben logopediste en wil helpen!<br />Stuur mij meer details:</label>
                <input name="naam_logo" id="naam_logo" type="text" placeholder="Voornaam Achternaam" required />
                <input name="email_logo" id="email_logo" type="email" placeholder="email" required />
                <input name="kind" type="hidden" value="logo" />
                <input name="submit_logo" id="submit_logo" type="submit" value="" /> 
            </form>
        </article>   
    </body>
</html>
```

If you remove the font-size at the keyframes it loads fine else it won't load.

CSS code:

```
#opzoek {
    opacity: 0.8;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width:6em;
    height:5em;
    border-radius:50%;
    font-size:1em;
    padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#F65292;
    shape-inside: circle();
    margin: 0.4em 0 0 0.4em;
    position:absolute;
    font-weight:bold; 
    display: absolute;
    animation:opzoek 5s 1;
    -moz-animation:opzoek 5s 1;
    -webkit-animation:opzoek 5s 1;
    -o-animation:opzoek 5s 1;
    }

@keyframes opzoek
{
    0%      {transform: rotate(0deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    25%     {transform: rotate(20deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    50%     {transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 0;}
    45%     {transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.0em;}
    70%     {transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%;background:#1ec7e6; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.0em;}
    80%     {transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.6em;}
    100%    {transform: rotate(-360deg);left:0px; top: 0; width:6em; height:5em; padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1em;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes opzoek
{
    0%      {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    25%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    50%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 0;}
    45%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.0em;}
    70%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%;background:#1ec7e6; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.0em;}
    80%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.6em;}
    100%    {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);left:0px; top: 0; width:6em; height:5em; padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1em;}
}

@-moz-keyframes opzoek
{
    0%   {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    25%  {-moz-transform: rotate(20deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    50%  {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 0;}
    55%  {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.0em;}
    70%  {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%;background:#1ec7e6; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.6em;}
    80%  {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 9em;}
    100% {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);left:0px; top: 0; width:6em; height:5em; padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1em;}
}

@-o-keyframes opzoek
{
    0%   {transform: rotate(0deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    25%  {transform: rotate(20deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    50%  {transform: rotate(0deg);left:50%; top: 0;}
    55%  {transform: rotate(0deg);left:50%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.0em;}
    70%  {transform: rotate(0deg);left:50%;background:#1ec7e6; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.0em;}
    80%  {transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1.6em;}
    100% {transform: rotate(-360deg);left:0px; top: 0; width:6em; height:5em; padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; font-size:1em;}
}
```

Comment: You need to share some of your code to help reproduce the issues as well as for future reference of this question on the site. Links to live pages are not desirable because once the problem is fixed, the reference material is gone.

Comment: I am sorry. I would have added the code that was causing the error if we could find it. I just have no idea where the problem could lie. So I added the complete page (html + css). As the same error happens when I remove the JS I didn't think it was needed to add that. Hope someone has an idea

Comment: You should try and create the simplest (shortest) program that still causes this issue to occur... the community here will simply overlook questions with a giant dump of code as it looks like the asker has put no thought into solving the problem. [Stack Overflow reference for Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have put thought in solving the problem as I first thought it had to do with the css animation. So I first added an empty 3d transform on the animation element to trigger 3d accelaration but it failed so after that I removed all animation code. Again failed. After removing all JS everything still failed. Lastly I removed the font-face again with no result.

It is just that the error does not make any sense. This is very simple & small webpage. Also I have no ipad or iphone to test so need to count on friends on fb. I can't bother them everytime I change 1 line of code.

Comment: Try fixing your [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flerenlezen.brokenhip.be%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1) and see if that solves your problem

Comment: Sadly that also did not change anything. I also removed the display: none; as I read this could make it difficult with ios8. Sadly it didn't make a difference.

I have shortend the html code above. If I would have a test machine I could make it much shorter but asking someone on fb each time I change something just doesn't work.

If anyone who has an ipad or iphone could help out that would be much appreceated. This is really a crazy error and I hope more people would like to know what causes it.

OK it is clearly a problem with the CSS. When I remove the CSS link it loads.

Comment: " they get an error " <-- What's the error?

Comment: In dutch it says: "Deze webpagina is opnieuw geladen vanwege een probleem" and "er heeft zich herhaaldelijk een probleem voorgedaan op 'http://lerenlezen.brokenhip.be'."

So in english it is more or less: "This webpage has been loaded again because of a problem" and "A re-occuring error is happening on 'http...'."

So to make it short the page is just not loaded. And they do not get anymore details

Comment: wow, I loaded your page with safari inspector connected and it crash

Comment: Yup. This is going to be a toughie to debug. As soon as mobile Safari encounters the problem, it closes the page, and therefore closes the remote debugging session, so it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: It's definitely the animation. I can reproduce it with http://jsfiddle.net/h18ordr0/6/ which has just the `/* Opzoek */` CSS.

Comment: But I already removed the complete animation once and it still didn't want to load. That was actually the first thing I tried. Will the page load for you when you remove the animation? I really would like to have an ipad/iphone right now. I am wondering is it than also not working on a mac?

Comment: It works fine on a Mac. I have removed the keyframes, and it loads fine in the Safari simulator, but bear in mind I'm using jsfiddle, which may give different results. I'm trying to narrow it down.

Comment: I removed the animation on http://lerenlezen.brokenhip.be/test2.php
If that runs fine I will edit my above css to only show the animation and keyframes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to lie with your font-size animation. Certainly, if I take your original code, put it in [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h18ordr0/) and run it in the iOS simulator, I can reproduce the crash. However, if I take that code and simply remove the font-size animations from the `@-webkit-keyframes` keyframes, as follows:

```
@-webkit-keyframes opzoek
{
    0%      {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    25%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);left:0px; top: 0;}
    50%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 0;}
    45%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em; }
    70%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%;background:#1ec7e6; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;}
    80%     {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);left:25%; top: 6em; width: 10em; height: 7em; padding: 4.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;}
    100%    {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);left:0px; top: 0; width:6em; height:5em; padding: 2.5em 1em 0.5em 1em;}
}
```

...which I've done in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h18ordr0/22/), then it no longer crashes, and the rest of the animation seems to work.

I'm afraid I don't know enough about CSS keyframe animation to know whether that's a problem with your code or a problem with mobile Safari, but that appears to be the issue. What you're trying to do looks sane enough to me, and I'd probably raise it as a bug (I'm guessing [with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com)).

My commiserations. It can't be easy to debug something like this when you don't have access to mobile Safari yourself. It was hard enough figuring it out with a full development rig...

If it helps anyone else figure out what's going on, here's a minimal reproduction. This code will work fine on desktop Safari, but crashes mobile Safari (in iOS 8.1, at least.)

Interestingly, it's only a problem with a combination of (a) the rotation, and (b) the `font-size` being specified in ems. If I change the font-size transition to use pixels, e.g. animate it to `20px` rather than `1em`, it works fine, so perhaps it's an em-calculation issue.

```css
#opzoek {
    -webkit-animation:opzoek 5s 1;
    /* 
       The display: block isn't necessary for bug reproduction;
       it just makes the animation actually do something on 
       non-mobile Safari. 
    */
    display: block; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes opzoek
{
    0%      {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100%    {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg); font-size: 1em; }
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="opzoek">Words</a>
```

[JSFiddle here if that makes it easier to see the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/h18ordr0/39/).

Comment: Edited the question. Cause I really would like to know why this is a problem. As far as I know it is the correct usage of css.

Comment: @brokenhip Seems reasonable. I just added a minimal reproducing case to my answer; it might help people track down what's happening. It looks like the combination of rotation and font-size. Interestingly, it looks like if you specify the font-size in pixels rather than ems, it works okay, so that might be a work-around for you. Maybe it's getting confused calculating the em-size while the thing's being transformed.